# What regular expression to use to replace code but keep a string/variable the same?

Tags: regex, expression, sublimetext3

I have a section of code like so:

```
$this->getUrl('example/page.html')
```

and I need to replace it to look like the following:

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct' => 'example/page.html'))
```

My code editor **(sublime text)** has regular expression find and replace, but how do I do this whilst keeping the 'example/page.html' string across all occurrences?

---

So substitution are: `'', array('_direct' => '` and `)` at the end

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

- find what: `(\$this->getUrl\()([^)]+)\)`
- replace: `$1'', array('_direct' => $2))`

Comment: You probably wanted to use `+` instead of `}` and you didn't close second capturing group.

Comment: +1, It was a little hard for me to figure out what meaning **negate**  `[^]` has, and with your mention to me about `)` missing at the end I got it down.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl-H` for invoking **replace** bar

then

find what: `(?<=\$this->getUrl\()([^)]+)`
Replace with: `'', array('_direct' => $1)`

---

first find a zero-match-length with **look-behind** and the capture between parentheses `()` to special variable **$1**

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There will be one `)` missing at the end.

Comment: @EganWolf | Thanks I see it now.

Comment: Should be fine now. However, I think you don't have to escape `-` character.